# Jquery change css of td inside odd tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the background of table cells in odd table rows and only certain cells with Jquery
I know I can do this to change the odd or even rows

```
$("#DisplayTable tr:visible:even").css("background", "#999999");
$("#DisplayTable tr:visible:odd").css("background", "#ffffff");
```

And I tried this but this

```
$('#DisplayTable td:Contains(' + $(this).val() + '):odd').css("background", "#A8CBFF");
$('#DisplayTable td:Contains(' + $(this).val() + '):even').css("background", "#66a3ff");
```

But this just takes the cell regardless of the row.
To better describe my problem I want to change the background to blue on certain cells but also have cells in an even row be darker.

How would I acheive this?

Comment: `$('#DisplayTable tr:contains(' + $(this).val() + '):odd').css("background", "#A8CBFF");
$('#DisplayTable tr:contains(' + $(this).val() + '):even').css("background", "#66a3ff");
`

Comment: What is `$(this)`?

Comment: As far as I know, `:contains` should be lower case, not upper case. However, it does not seem to be your (only) problem here. It would help a lot if you added a snipped replicating the problem (in your question). My guts tell me that we are missing some important parts to solve your problem.

Comment: @Rayon i need to change the cell not the row

Comment: @choz it is the value from a search field

Comment: @RobertHolden, Well in that case, `.filter` the `even/odd` rows and then appy our logic..Makes sense ?

Comment: @Roque i have a jquery expression that is `jQuery.expr[":"].Contains` which is case insensitive

Comment: If you're trying to change the style of `td` inside of `odd tr`, then you should do `$('#DisplayTable tr:odd td:contains("' + $(this).val() + '"').css()` instead.

Comment: @choz That worked thanks

Comment: It seems you are right. I cannot find any documentation on this but apparently, `":Contains"` works too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with this `:Contains(' + $(this).val() + ')` part

You may need to put the value in double quotes like `':contains("' + $(this).val() + '")'`

Also note as according to this [link](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) it has to be `:contains`.

See the prototype below.

```js
$('#DisplayTable td:contains("1"):odd').css("background", "yellow");
$('#DisplayTable td:contains("2"):even').css("background", "orange");
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="DisplayTable">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You missed `'` after `$(this).val()`. And you're selecting `odd` and `even` tds, while OP needs to select tds in `odd` rows.

Comment: I think the aim of @user2181397's snippet is just to be an example of a working `:contains` selector. The answer to OP's problem is "put the value in double quotes". I think this is a good, informative and generalisable answer.

Answer (score 0):

choz suggested `$('#DisplayTable tr:odd td:contains("' + $(this).val() + '"').css()` and this seems to do exactly what I want

this does what I want (edited from user2181397 suggestion)

```js
$('#DisplayTable tr:even td:contains("1")').css("background", "yellow");
$('#DisplayTable tr:odd td:contains("1")').css("background", "orange");
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="DisplayTable">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer was already provided by @user2181397 below. I do think you should accept it.

Comment: @Roque They're totally different answers.

Comment: It adds the `"` on the contains selector which, I think, was your problem.

Comment: @Roque And OP wants to select odd rows, not odd columns.